# How to set a Label position after a timer ends, in a repetitive structure?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I have this fragment of code. It moves a pawn on a board.

```
while(i<end)
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
    Label.setBounds(x+i, y, xsize, ysize);
    i++;
}
```

My problem:
The Label gets set only once, after all the time(`end` seconds) passes.

Also tried:
1:

```
while(i<end)
{
    for(int v;v<9999999;v++);
    Label.setBounds(x+i, y, xsize, ysize);
    i++;
}
```

2:

```
while(i<end)
{
    for(int v;v<9999999;v++)
    {
        Label.setBounds(x+i, y, xsize, ysize);
    }
    i++;
}
```

With same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Label gets set only once, after all the time(end seconds) passes.

The problem is the `Thread.sleep(...)` is invoked from the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which prevents the GUI from repainting itself until the loop is finished executing.

Don't use `Thread.sleep()` on the `EDT`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on why this happens.

The simple solution is to use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the events. The tutorial also has a section on `How to Use a Swing Timer` which contains a working example to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

> Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on why this happens.

Using `javax.swing.Timer` I modified the code to this form:

```
int delay = 1000;

ActionListener taskPerformer = (ActionEvent evt) -> 
{
    Label.setBounds(x+1, y, xsize, ysize);    
    if(condition)
    {
        timer.stop();
    }
};

timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

It now works as intended.